# Does checkmarx support python's cherrypy framework?

Tags: python-3.x, cherrypy, checkmarx

Hi i am using checkmarx for static code analysis. The checkmarx document says it only supports Django framework from python. May i know if checkmarx supports python's cherrypy framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with checkmarx is the version of Python. Checkmarx support Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.4 .

Python version more recent that 3.4 are not supported and you may experience parsing or analyse issues